# Determine current "environment"

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Is there a way to detect if I'm looking at a PowerApp in the editor or the published version? Something like `If(ENVIRONMENT_EDITOR, foo)`

I have some code in my OnStart that sets a bunch of defaults for my development/testing ease, but which should not get published … which I've accidentally done a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "way" to do this but you have to be using Solutions https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/environment-variables-available-in-preview/.

Many people in the PowerApps community forums have brought this up. Last I saw it was ["Under Review"](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Get-environment-ID-within-Flow-or-app/idi-p/296518).